# Refactor Javascript to Optimize for Speed

Tags: javascript, optimization, refactoring

I was able to figure out a working solution to the problem but I would like to know how I could go about refactoring this code to make it faster. Thank you.

```js
/*
    Given a sequence of integers as an array, determine whether it is     
    possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more 
    than one element from the array.
    */

//var array2 = [0, -2, 5, 6]; // expect true
//var array2 = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]; // expect false
var array2 = [1, 2, 5, 5, 5] // expect false

function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
  let passing = false;
  sequence.forEach((number, idx, array) => {
    let sequence2 = sequence.filter((num, id) => id !== idx);

    let answer = sequence2.every((num, idx, array) => {
      return idx === sequence2.length - 1 || num < sequence2[idx + 1];
    });

    if (answer) {
      passing = true;
    }

  });
  return passing;
}

console.log(almostIncreasingSequence(array2));
```

Comment: refactoring = for readability optimizing = for speed

Comment: @dustytrash: refactoring == restructuring to achieve another purpose.   Readability and speed are *both* purposes.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the problem right, you only need to make 1 pass through the sequence. You're looking for arrays where the difference between index (i-1) and (i) decreases only one time in the whole array.

(this code has gone through several edits to handle edge cases)

```
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
    if(sequence.length == 1)
        return true;

    var countDecreases = 0;
    var i = -1;
    for(var index=1; index<sequence.length; index++)
    {
        if(sequence[index-1] > sequence[index])
        {
            countDecreases++;
            i = index;
            if(countDecreases > 1)
                return false;
        }
    }
    var canRemovePreviousElement = (i == 1 || sequence[i-2] <= sequence[i]);
    var cannotRemoveSelectedElement = (i+1 < sequence.length && sequence[i-1] > sequence[i+1]);

    if(canRemovePreviousElement)
        return cannotRemoveSelectedElement;

    return (countDecreases == 1 && !cannotRemoveSelectedElement);
}

// Testing /////////////////////////////////

var passTestCases = {
    "remove index 0": [2, 0, 1, 2],
    "remove index 1": [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    "remove index (last-1)": [0, 1, -1, 2],
    "remove index (last)": [0, 1, 2, -1],
    "remove only element": [1]
};
var failTestCases = {
    "remove index 0 or 1": [0, -1, 1, 2],
    "remove any index, all increasing": [1, 2, 5, 5, 5],
    "remove any index, with decrease": [1, 0],
    "one decrease": [0, 1, 2, 0, 1],
    "two decreases": [1, 0, 2, 1],
    "no elements to remove": []
};

runTests(passTestCases, true, almostIncreasingSequence);
runTests(failTestCases, false, almostIncreasingSequence);

function runTests(testCases, expectedResult, method) {
    console.log("\nShould Return " + expectedResult);
    for(var key in testCases)
    {
        var testCase = testCases[key];
        var result = method(testCase);
        console.log(key + ": " + testCase + ": result " + result); 
    }
}
```

On optimizing for speed:

This method will only make one pass through the array, while the original post uses nested loops. In general, a linear algorithm will be faster than a non-linear algorithm for large data sets.

Comparing the speeds of the two algorithms with these tiny test cases gives inconclusive results.

Comment: the requirements is "removing no more than one element" so: return (countDecreases <= 1)

Comment: @Piero but the example says [1,2,5,5,5] should return false.

Comment: @Macrunning "sequence.forEach", "sequence.filter", and "sequence.every" are all loops. There is no particular difference between those and a "for" loop.

Comment: the loops in your example are NESTED loops. This result in slow performance versus a single loop.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to understand where in the for loop it it removing element if needed to check for an almost increasing sequence. Is this not checking agains all of the elements in the array?

Comment: hi Piero, yes Without Haste's solution does not work. [1,2,3,4,5] produces a false answer and should be true. –

Comment: As you noticed Macrunning, also [40, 50, 60, 10, 20, 30] is returning true but should be false

Comment: @Piero Oh, you're correct, that test case does fail.

Comment: @Without Haste still not correct. [1, 2, 1, 2] should be false but is true, [10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] should be true but is false, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 6] should false but is true, [1, 1] should be true but is false.

Comment: @WithoutHaste you will want to have a look at the following link as well. There are very big differences when it comes to speed optimization. [performance analysis](https://github.com/dg92/Performance-Analysis-JS)

Comment: I think you may want to rethink what the actual problem is asking. your latest solution does not work either. [1, 3, 2] expected output should be true, but is false. [0, -2, 5, 6] should be true but is false. [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 6] should be false but is true.  [1, 1] should be true but is false. [1, 2, 5, 3, 5] should be true but is false. [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6] should be true but is false.

Comment: @Macrunning My answer is based on interpreting the original description "by removing no more than one element" to mean that if there is more than 1 possible element whose removal would result in an increasing array, then the answer is false. This interpretation is consistent with the original test case "[1, 1, 1, 2, 3]" expecting false. So in the [1,3,2] example you listed, since either the 3 or the 2 could be removed, the result is false. If I'm way off base, I'd be interested in seeing your solution to the problem.

Comment: @Macrunning I just noticed you are the original poster. Could you update your post with a more detailed explanation of the problem? I must have the wrong idea about it.

Comment: @Without Hast here is some additional example information:

For sequence = [1, 3, 2, 1], the output should be
almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = false.

There is no one element in this array that can be removed in order to get a strictly increasing sequence.

For sequence = [1, 3, 2], the output should be
almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = true.

You can remove 3 from the array to get the strictly increasing sequence [1, 2]. Alternately, you can remove 2 to get the strictly increasing sequence [1, 3].

Comment: Return true if it is possible to remove one element from the array in order to get a strictly increasing sequence, otherwise return false.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we have a conflict when a[i] <= a[i - 1] as we want a strictly increasing sequence. There are two ways to solve the conflict. One is to remove a[i] from the array, hoping that a[i + 1] won't conflict with a[i - 1]. Another is to remove a[i - 1], hoping that a[i - 2] won't conflict with a[i].

As we have the case that a[i] <= a[i - 1], it should be better to remove a[i - 1] so that our new max element in the sequence is less or equal than before, thus giving more chances to have no conflict on next element. So if we can choose between removing a[i] and a[i - 1], removing a[i - 1] would be better.

We can remove a[i - 1] when a[i - 2] does not conflict with a[i]. In the code, sequence[prev - 1] is this a[i - 2], so in the case where there is a conflict, our only choice left is removing a[i].

To avoid actually removing elements on the array, I used the little trick of just doing a continue, which makes i increase but prev stays the same, thus making the new a[i] compare against a[i - 2] as they should be now next to each other in the strictly increasing sequence.

When we don't fall into the continue, we do prev = i instead of prev += 1 because we would actually need to add 2 to prev after we got into the continue and there was no conflict between a[i] and a[i - 2]. If we added just 1 to prev, we would have prev pointing to a[i - 1], but we can't have that as its the element we "removed" from the sequence.

```js
function isAlmostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
  var prev = 0;
  var removed = false;
  
  for (var i = 1; i < sequence.length; i++) {
    if (sequence[i] <= sequence[prev]) {
      if (removed == false) {
        removed = true;
        if (prev > 0 && sequence[i] <= sequence[prev - 1]) { // need to remove sequence[i] instead of sequence[prev]
          continue;           
        }
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    prev = i;
  }
  
  return true;
}

var tests = [[0, -2, 5, 6], [1, 1, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 5, 5, 5], [1, 3, 2], [0, -2, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 6], [1, 1], [1, 2, 5, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6]];

tests.forEach(function(arr){
  console.log(arr.join(","), isAlmostIncreasingSequence(arr));
});
```

Comment: thanks that passed all the tests. Now trying to process. :)

Comment: can you explain this part `if (prev > 0 && sequence[i] <= sequence[prev - 1]) { // need to remove sequence[i] instead of sequence[prev]
          continue;           
        }` I'm having trouble understanding how we don't get a return false when using the following array [10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] (which should return true). I'm going through the code and wouldn't we run in to false on the initial pass because prev = 0. I think I'm not understanding something.

Comment: @Macrunning added a bit of explanation. As for [10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], when prev = 0 we do not use continue but we don't do return false, return false is the else for the removed == false condition ^^